# Where can I download namecoin client?

Tags: client, namecoin

I got bitcoin I got litecoin.

Now, where can I download namecoin client?

I don't see it here.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Namecoin

A wallet client that can do many coins at the same time would be nice

Comment: http://dot-bit.org/Main_Page Ctrl-F "Download"